# Is there a difference in reading power for 3 phase as opposed to 3 single phases?

Tags: power, three-phase

I have 3 phase supply to my house.  And I have solar on two phases, that use 2XTesla Powerwall 2 batteries. Based on the Tesla reports, my power bill should be a lot lower than the charge of $400 to $800 for months/years.

A few months ago, I transferred everything over from the third phase to the other two phases, except a heat pump which is normally off, and a pottery kiln that I havent connected up yet.  And I installed more solar panels and second battery. Now the power bill should be $50 odd dollars, yet my power bill attack continued.  It didnt even dip.

When I complained to the Utility, they insisted that I had a single phase meter.  This is a lie as I could see the power used on all three phases, by pressing a button on it.  While I was on holiday, they came and upgraded the meter.  Now I can only see one reading.  I still have a three phase supply.

My knowledge of high voltage electrics is limited.  And I have forgotten most of my 3 phase knowledge, not having used it for 40 years.

Question : Is it possible to read the power as 3 phase which may give a drastically different figure than reading it as three different single phases.  Keeping in mind that the consumption is severely unbalanced.

Note : here in NZ, the have three phase on the street, and distribute the phases along the street, providing single phase power to homes.  Because of high consumption, I have a 3 phase supply.

Comment: *Question* <--Not if wired correctly.